# Responsive popup notification with css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

In my webpage I created a new notification center popup but I can't understand how to change my css from "normal mode" to "responsive mode".

This is my popup:

Icon to open the notification center
[image: Icon to open the notification center]

In a "big" web page, i see the popup as follow
[image]

If i open the page in my mobile browser, i see the popup as follow
[image]

This is my css and html code:

```
<div>
    <div id="noti_Container">
        <div id="noti_Button">
           <button></button>
        </div>
        <div id="notifications" style="margin-top: 13px;">
             <h3>Notifiche</h3>
             <div style="height:200px;"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>


#noti_Container
{
    position:relative;
}

#notifications {
    display:none;
    width:330px;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    right:-30;
    background:#FFF;
    border:solid 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, .20);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .20);
    z-index: 0;
}

#notifications:before {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    color:transparent;
    border:10px solid #CCC;
    border-color:transparent transparent #FFF;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-left:268px;
}

h3 {
    display:block;
    color:#333;
    background:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:8px;
    margin:0;
    border-bottom:solid 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, .30);
}
```

How can I change my popup to responsive mode?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using media queries ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Anyway, I never used the media queries in css...i used bootstrap libraryto manage some features in responsive mode but i cannot apply this library in my popup...

Comment: Have you tried to set min-width (in this case 330px) and max-width (in this case 100%) instead of width? Setting the width hardcoded will always give you trouble going responsive. If the width is set to 330px and the viewport is 200px, the element will  get out of boundaries.

Comment: @teefars thanks! you're right about the width...anyway, I tried the changes mentioned by you but doesn't works :( the result is the same...

Comment: im suprised a 330px plus 30px margin which is a total of 360px covers the whole screen. I think the problem is with your (<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">)  give it a lower scale like .9 or .8 and it will be ok

Answer (score 1):

Try using `width:100%` and `max-width:330px` on css. As I said, using hardcoded width will be always respected regardless of viewport width.

I made a sample with `max-width:600px`.

[Pen](http://codepen.io/teefars/pen/LNEove?#)

Comment: I tried your code (copy and paste of your css) and this is the result: http://i.imgur.com/ELPkucI.png

Comment: Neither do I. Try to post the complete solution with some online code program, like codepen, so we can simulate the problem. Otherwise we cannot help :(

Comment: Thanks for your support man! Tomorrow I will try to check your solution with a friend...if I don't solve, I will let you now and I will post the code :)